# Put server name in TSQL Query

Tags: sql-server

Is there any issue if I put server name in the query of view or query of procedure?

ex.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.View_Name
AS
SELECT * FROM Server_Name.Database_Name.dbo.Table_Name
GO

OR

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Procedure_Name
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM Server_Name.Database_Name.dbo.Table_Name
END
GO
```

Please advise

Comment: `Server_Name.dbo.Table_Name` that isn't what that represents. That's **`DatabaseName`** `.SchemaName.ObjectName`. If you *need* the server name in the reference, you need to use 4 part naming: `ServerName.DatabaseName.SchemaName.ObjectName`

Comment: Hello Larnu, sorry I miss that. I already corrected my example. Thank you

Comment: Well, if you're referencing a database on a different server, then you *need* to use 4 part naming. That use use a `SYNONYM`.

Comment: Actually it's on the same server. I don't know why someone in my team create the view or procedure like that. So I want to know is there any issue like slow performance or any else if we do like that.

Comment: It is fine as long as you don't need a working copy of a database on a different server. And because it is common to need one for development or testing, I would prefer to not use 4 part names unless it is a linked server.

Comment: I do, however, beleieve that using 4 part naming results in a performance loss.

Comment: @Larnu  Well, 4 part naming isn't normally used when it's for databases on the same server. Since there's no reason to do that. But if that would cause a performance loss, would that then mean 4 part naming could have an impact on the actual execution plan?

Comment: It's something I recall seeing awhile ago, I think from Bertrand @LukStorms . I didn't have a chance to look earlier, but sure I've seen it.